# custom field formula

Tags: custom-object, formula, formula-field, custom-field, sum

I have two custom objects.
Reservation__c and MoneyReceived__c and they are lookup relationship.

I want Reservation__c.totalReceived__c = sum of all MoneyReceived__c.amountReceived__c.

[image: These are Money Received in list view.]

There are one or more amountReceived__c per reservation.

I need help with writing formula calculating

> sum of (amountReceived__c) = totalReceived__c

Or do I have to write a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rolling up lookup objects, you will have to write custom code.

You can also levarage [Declarative Rollup Summary Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/07/a-declarative-rollup-summary-tool-for-force-com-lookup-relationships.html)

You can also refer this [blog](https://blog.texei.com/how-to-create-rollup-summaries-in-a-declarative-way-in-salesforce-f1272b846e06) for step by step instructions

In case you want to write custom code, you can refer [this](https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/30/roll-up-summary-fields-with-lookup-relationships-part-1/) link, which uses a trigger to rollup.

Answer (score 1):

@Logan H since the relationship is lookup relationship you need to write custom code(apex trigger) which you can easily find on internet.